# twilio receive text basic authentication

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Trying to implement security with the inbound communication from twilio
https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security

I understand how the validating twilio request works. However I am having trouble understanding the basic http-authentication. Namely,

`If you specify a password-protected URL, Twilio will first send a request with no Authorization header. After your server responds with a 401 Unauthorized status code, a WWW-Authenticate header and a realm in the response, Twilio will make the same request with an Authorization header.`

Does this mean twilio will send us a request without any username or password, then we will responds with 401 and they will make the same request but with the username and password? So there are two trips? what's the point of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the point is so your server can respond with the relevant type of authorization it expects in the `WWW-Authenticate` header so that Twilio knows whether to use basic or digest to authenticate.

It's pretty standard HTTP stuff...

Comment: It's standard HTTP stuff to make two trips for basic auth?? I thought that was the case only for digest. So for Twilio even if we opt for basic auth, we still have to do two trips everytime? And from what you said the first call is basically to tell twilio we are going to be using basic auth. Then they send the password in plain text over ssl on the second call???

Comment: Yes, it's standard HTTP stuff to do two trips for basic auth. You can read all about it here: `https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-2.1` Two trips for Twilio, two trips for everyone, thats how standards work. It sounds like you are getting the hang of how challenge/response works.